# httpclient is not working from .net6 in corporate proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have tried below -

Tried to fiddle with proxy and credentials for httpclient object creation.
Checked the code executes outside VPN and doesn't Inside VPN.
Tried downloading code from this repo and tried to replicate under my office proxy it doesn't work only for .net6 example. It is working for .net5 and below all the time. .net6 example I'm referring to AspNetCore.Docs/aspnetcore/fundamentals/http-requests/samples/6.x/HttpRequestsConsoleSample/
Tried degrading Microsoft.Extensions.Http package (from 6.0.0 to 2.1.1 and everything in between) in the sample code from this repo on .net6 example.
No what matter I did .net6 httpclient.sendAsync method calls are always resulting in below errors. Can someone please help.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.'

IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine..

SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Comment: Hi @Saiteja Samala, I have tested the code by using `AspNetCore.Docs/aspnetcore/fundamentals/http-requests/samples/6.x/HttpRequestsConsoleSample/ `. It works well. Maybe you need use Fiddler to catch the request and check where makes error.

Comment: Hi @Rena Yes the code from above links works for me as well outside VPN. When I'm inside VPN is the problem however similar code which is in .net5 (below is the url) is working me for both inside and outside vpn which is not the case with .net6. Can you please help me with what I'm missing here.

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/http-requests/samples/5.x/HttpClientFactoryConsoleSample

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and added a runtimeconfig.template.json file to the project (.NET 6) with the following in it:

```
{
  "configProperties": {
    "System.Net.DisableIPv6": "true"
  }
}
```

And this resolved my issue.

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62825